# Adding methods to an asyncio Transport

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

Is it possible to add new methods to a standard asyncio transport?

e.g: Adding a send method to the SSL transport that serializes a protocol buffer, constructs a frame and uses the transports own write method to do a buffered write to the underlying socket.

There are plenty of asyncio server/client examples out there, but I have not been able to find ones that implement their own transport or extends an already existing one.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot add a new method or inherit from existing asyncio transport.
Consider transports as *final* or *sealed*, like sockets.

You should never want to inherit from socket but make your class that embeds the socket instance inside, right?

The same for transport. See `asyncio.streams` as example of building new API layer on top of transport/protocol pair.